# Close socket when game ends

Tags: python, sockets, blender

I wrote a script in blender game and I use sockets, I have a Server.blend and a client.blend.

this is my Server's Constructor:

```
class Server:

def __init__(self, host="127.0.0.1", port= 9238):

    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    self.socket.setblocking(False)
    self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.socket.bind((host, port))
```

and this is my client's:

```
class Client:

def __init__(self, server_ip="127.0.0.1", server_port= 9238):

    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    self.socket.setblocking(False)

    self.serv_addr = (server_ip, server_port)
```

The problem is that I don't know when the client is going to exit the game, so I can't close his socket- what keeps the used port open so i can't use the current port again.

I have a dictionary which contains all the addresses of all the clients, so I tried to send a message to all the addresses and in case that the client disconnected, i won't be able to send the message and use and exception to remove the address from the list (and it's avatar etc..):

```
def Check_For_Disconnect(self):
    for addr in self.addr_user:
        try:
            self.socket.sendto(b"You are connected!" , addr)
        except socket.error:
            scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
            for obj in scene.objects:
                if str(obj) == "Text" and obj == self.addr_user[addr].name:
                    obj.delete()
                    del self.addr_user[addr]
```

I suppose that I don't reach the exception because the client's socket is still open so the message arrives properly.

Does anyone have any idea how I can around this problem?

Comment: please provide some code - how do you track the users action and etc. if you don't track his/her activity, it's really hard to get informed when he/she leaves the game.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. When client disconnects, a disconnet event is communicated (I assume TCP).

Comment: This is the problem.. i don't use TCP, i have edited my question and added some code, so now you can see i don't use it..

Answer (score 0):

The client should send some info about exiting the game, thus the server knows exactly when to close the socket. So the process is triggered by the client side.

Comment: So you'r advice is to send a message to the client that asks him if he really want to leave? and then i'll be able to know that he is exiting? it's a good idea but i still have the problem that in blender the client can press esc whenever he wants and close the game.. Then i am not able to know that he left..

Comment: You do not have to ask the client. If he stop the process it will send a signal to the server. The client program does not allow to exit from program until automated leaving message is not sent.

Comment: but the client didn't close the socket, the port is still open and he still can get messages, he can't show them because there is no code that can do it. Before the client stops the process he has to close it's socket. I suppose that the signal is being sent when the client stops the socket.

Comment: Furthermore, notice i'm using: self.socket.setblocking(False) in the sever.. I guess this is the reason that the client is still connected

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: I don't know when the client is going to exit the game, so I can't close his socket, what I do know is that just when the client runs his game- he can send messages to the server. so as long as the server on air he asks from the client for "connected" message. Every time that the server doesn't get a message from the client, he counts it. Now it's up to you how many counts to do until you sure that the client disconnected.

This is my receive method:

```
def receive(self):

    while True:
        for k in self.addr_connected:
            if self.addr_connected[k] > 50:
                self.Remove_Client(k)
                break

        try:

            data, addr = self.socket.recvfrom(1024)

            if not addr in self.addr_user:

                user= User(data.decode())

                scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
                spawner = scene.objects['Spawner']
                avatar = scene.addObject("Avatar", spawner)
                avatar.children[0]['Text'] = user.name
                avatar['user']= user 

                self.addr_user[addr] = user
                self.addr_connected[addr] = 0

            else:
                user= self.addr_user[addr]
                try:
                    user.keyboard.updateState(pickle.loads(data))
                except:
                    data = data.decode()
                    if data == "I am connected":
                        self.addr_connected[addr] = 0
                        for k in self.addr_connected:
                            if k != addr:
                                self.addr_connected[k] += 1

        except socket.error:
            for k in self.addr_connected:
                self.addr_connected[k] += 1     
            break
```